# Laravel collection multi level groupBy insert new items without checking each level's key

Tags: php, laravel, collections, grouping

Laravel collections now have a great multi-level groupBy function built in, but I am struggling with a sensible way to insert new items.

For example:

```
$this->myCollection = EloquentModel::all()->groupBy(['key1','key2','key3','key4']);
```

Very nice, easy to set up and access.  For this example, I will assume each key is a number

```
$this->myCollection[1][2][3][4] = new EloquentModel([insert => stuffHere]);
```

If there are already items in the nested positions [1], [2], and [3] then I can add a new item or overwrite the existing item at [4], but if any of the nested positions 1 through 3 is missing I get an error

```
Undefined offset: 1   (or 2 or 3 depending upon which is missing)
```

At the moment I am calling an insert into structure function with:

```
if (!$this->myCollection->has($1)) {
    $this->myCollection[$1] = new Collection;
}
if (!$this->myCollection[$1]->has($2)) {
    $this->myCollection[$1][$2] = new Collection;
}
if (!$this->myCollection[$1][$2]->has($3)) {
    $this->myCollection[$1][$2][$3] = new Collection;
}
$this->myCollection[$1][$2][$3][$4] = $itemFor4;
```

I find the groupBy nesting very useful, apart from not handling my inserts cleanly.

Some sample data - please assume there are > 100k records like this:

```
['username'=> 'a user name', 'course', => 'a coursename', 'activity_type' => 'one of 100s of activity names', 'reporting_week' => 23 // One of 52 weeks, [lots more data]]
['username'=> 'another user name', 'course', => 'another coursename', 'activity_type' => 'one of 100s of activity names', 'reporting_week' => 23 // One of 52 weeks, [lots more data]]
['username'=> 'a user name', 'course', => 'another coursename', 'activity_type' => 'one of 100s of activity names', 'reporting_week' => 24 // One of 52 weeks, [lots more data]]
['username'=> 'another user name', 'course', => 'a coursename', 'activity_type' => 'one of 100s of activity names', 'reporting_week' => 24 // One of 52 weeks, [lots more data]]
```

Instead of username and course in real life it would be a code representing that specific user and that course.

The data would include minutes of activity, counts of activity, grade of activity, how early or late the activity was etc.

Comment: I think null safe operator will help you https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator

Comment: @Eklavya - can you give an example of how to use the null safe operator when assigning an array / Laravel collection value?

Comment: @brianlmerritt can you share some sample data? And you can read about null safe operator in detail here [Null Safe Operator](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator)

Comment: I think you can set a default value for `'key1','key2','key3','key4'` if it's empty before groupBy to make sure key always exist

Comment: Regarding null safe operator, that is exactly what I want except instead of null I need a new empty collection inserted

Comment: null safe operator is read only, my suggest to retrieve something like that: `$collection = $this->myCollection->toArray(); data_set($collection,"$key1.$key2.$key3.$key4", $itemFor4, false)` but `$collection` variable is an array so if you want collection you have to cast it to collection and remember to pass `false` to `data_set` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could [extend the collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections), adding a custom `insertDeep` function.

An idea:

```
Collection::macro('insertDeep', function (array $path, $value) {
    $key = array_shift($path);
   
    if (count($path) === 0) {
        $this->put($key, $value);
        return $this;
    }

    if (!$this->has($key)) {
        $this->put($key, new Collection());
    }

    return $this->get($key)->insertDeep($path, $value);
});
```

Then you could simply call this method on your collection:

```
$this->myCollection->insertDeep([$1, $2, $3, $4], $itemFor4);
```

I just tried it and it should work properly:

```
$coll = new Collection();
$coll->insertDeep(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'test');

$coll->toArray();
// Result
   [
     "a" => [
       "b" => [
         "c" => [
           "d" => "test",
         ],
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

*Disclaimer: this function will fail if you specify a path where a key already exists but whose value is not a collection*